# How to implement infinite ajax scroll pagination in Codeiginiter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, pagination

I want to use infinite ajax scroll pagination for my blog, but unfortunately I do not have a result!? I still get this error message : server not responding... Below the code used.

```
function loadMoreData(page){
  $.ajax(
        {
            url: '<?php echo base_url();?>welcome/index',
            method: "post",
            data:{page:page},
            beforeSend: function()
            {
                $('.ajax-load').show();

            }

        })

        .done(function(data)

        {
            if(data == ""){ 
                $('.ajax-load').html("No more records found");

                return;
            }
            $('.ajax-load').hide();
            $("#result1").append(data);
        })
        .fail(function(ajaxOptions, thrownError)
        {
              alert('server not responding...');
        });

}

    var page = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) {
     page++;
     loadMoreData(page);

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to debug the Network Traffic ? (F12)
Is the url correct ?

Comment: header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin,Content-Type,Authorization, X-Auth-Token');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE,HEAD,OPTIONS");

Comment: Could you View at the outgoing Traffic via Browser Developer Tools ?